# calling javascript function from PHP - quotes issue

Tags: javascript, php, quotes

I'm trying to call javascript function from PHP. the idea is to create each parameter from file as link that when clicked inputs it's value into text box.

```
$lines = file('http://localhost/repositories.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo  "<a onclick='javascript:(document.folderForm.folderLocation.value=".htmlspecialchars($line) .");' href='#'>".htmlspecialchars($line) . "</a><br />";
}
```

when clicking the created links I'm getting (for example):

```
ReferenceError: test2 is not defined
```

I think there should be quotation marks around the parameter, but I can't add them. I tried to use ' \" ' without success. 
any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell us something about test2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote and properly escape the JavaScript string that you're assigning to the input `value` property. You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for that:

```
echo "<a onclick='document.folderForm.folderLocation.value=".htmlspecialchars(json_encode($line)) .";' href='#'>".htmlspecialchars($line) . "</a><br />";
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7Rl32Z)

---

The main cause of the issue is that your code was missing the quotes around the string value, so JavaScript was interpreting it as an identifier (variable name).

`json_encode` adds quotes around the value and, more importantly, escapes the value to make sure it is a valid JSON string (it escapes line feeds, carriage returns and quotes which could easily result in a syntax error otherwise).

JSON is a subset of the JavaScript syntax, so any valid JSON is valid JavaScript. (provided it is used in a suitable context)

Finally, as the value is inside an HTML attribute, `htmlspecialchars` is still applied to escape the value. It escapes quotes to make sure the variable value does not break out of the attribute value and also escapes characters such as `&` to not be interpreted as the beginning of an HTML entity sequence.

---

Finally, I would recommend against `echo` in this case, as to reduce the number of quotes and make interpolation easier to read:

```
$lines = file('http://localhost/repositories.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) { ?>
    <a onclick='document.folderForm.folderLocation.value=<?= htmlspecialchars(json_encode($line)) ?>;' href='#'><?= htmlspecialchars($line) ?></a><br />
<?php } ?>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/z9hC3o)

Note: PHP short echo tags are available everywhere independent of configuration as of PHP 5.4. Switch `<?=` to `<?php echo` if you need to support PHP < 5.4.

Comment: No problem. I've just added some more in-depth explanation as well.